# using wc_mail with attachment

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, email-attachments

I have a custom WooCommerce email that needs to send to the third party. 
In this email, I have to add an attachment. I tried with `wc_mail()` but the attachment not attached.

Here is how it look likes:

```
$attachment = array();
ob_start(); 
include('some-html-email-content.php');
$message = ob_get_clean();
$attachment[] = get_template_directory() . '/some.pdf';
wc_mail('xxx@example.com', 'some subject ', $message, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n", $attachment);
```

I can receive the email without any problem, only the attachment is not there. 
What did I done wrong?

I can't use `woocommerce_email_attachments` filter hook, because this mail isn't attached to any regular woocommerce mail (new order, process, new user etc....).

I also tried with `wp_mail()` still I cannot make it through.

Answer (score 2):

```
$attachment = array(  WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/my-plugin/uploads/sample_photo_01.jpg' );
```

Attachments should always use the absolute filesystem path. Change location/name of file based on where the attachment is located.

Sources:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_content_type

Comment: `absolute filesystem path` was the part I missed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? I think the way you are assigning values to the array variable might be incorrect?

$getAttachment = get_template_directory() . '/some.pdf';

$attachment = array("{$getAttachment}");

corrected, sorry.

Comment: Tried your method, still not working. The path of the file is correct. I wonder any way to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out is the directory permission issue. 
So, change the upload directory to 755 and it works.
Thanks for the helps.